# SQL show the same id in 2 pages

Tags: sql, subquery

I have "users" table in sql.

```
id | name    | sex | looking4 | status | age 
---+---------+-----+----------+--------+-----
1  | omer    | 1   | 2        | 3      | 24
2  | yossi   | 1   | 3        | 3      | 26
3  | nitzan  | 2   | 1        | 3      | 25
```

sex:

```
1 - men
2 - girl
```

I have this sql:

```
SELECT id, name, city, age, birthday, sex, online
FROM `users` 
WHERE `active`='1' AND (`status` IN (7,8,9,109,110)) AND (`age` between 18 AND 55) 
AND  (`sex`='1' AND `looking4`='3') OR (`sex`='1' AND `looking4`='2') OR (`sex`='2' AND `looking4`='2') OR (`sex`='2' AND `looking4`='3') 
ORDER by online desc
LIMIT 10, 10
```

The problem:
My website show duplicate ids

```
User id 40 in page 1
User id 40 in page 2
```

How can I fix my sql query?

Comment: Your ordering is not consistent, try `ORDER BY online DESC, id`

Answer (score 0):

Your table data is missing some columns. What is in the column online? Additionally what is the primary key in your table `users`. Maybe it is natural that you have duplicate keys.

You should ask yourself: What data do I want to display? and What order is required?

Try the following to find out more about the duplicates: `ORDER BY ID, online DESC`

Answer (score 0):

`online` sounds like a flag.  That means that the sorting is *unstable*.  I would suggest adding an additional column so the sorting is repeatable:

```
order by online, id
```